# ReLU Neuron Derivative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, derivative

For $x \in \mathbb R^d$, we define:
$$
\text{ReLU}(x) := \max{(x, 0)} \\
\text{Step}(x) := \mathbb{1}[x \ge 0]
$$
And ‘a neuron of the activation function $\psi$’ as $f_{\psi,w,b}(x) := \psi(w \cdot x - b)$, where $w  \in \mathbb{R^d}, b \in \mathbb R$.

The question is how to approximate (w.r.t. the $L^2$ norm) the output of $f_{\text{Step},,}()$ using a linear combination of $f_{\text{ReLU},_1,_1}(x)$ and $f_{\text{ReLU},_2,_2}(x)$, where we can choose $_1,_2,_1,_2$.

Comment: $\max(n x + 1, 0) - \max(n x, 0)$ converges to the unit step function as $n \to \infty$ — is that what you are after?

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Actually, I'm after understanding Proposition 3 (and 4) in [BELM20](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.02855.pdf). In other words, why the following holds?
$$\lim_{\delta \to \infty} \frac {\max \left( (u + \delta v) \cdot x - b, 0 \right) - \max \left( u \cdot x - b, 0  \right)} {\delta} = \mathbb{1} [x \ge 0] v \cdot x$$

Comment: if you're asking how to demonstrate the result in your comment, you should edit that into your post.